# Responsive centering of image in table

Tags: javascript, css

In a responsive `table` I would like the left column (25%) to contain a one cell `table` with a margin of "1vw 2vw 1vw 2vw" or the appropriate padding of its parent element. The `table` will contain an `image` of arbitrary size (both bigger or smaller than the limits below) that should be centered vertically and horizontally in its parent `table`. The `image` (or the `table` above it) should have a maximum size of 200px and a minimum size of 64px. In addition the immediate parent of the `image` element should be a `figure` element with a `figcaption` sibling.

What CSS would design this structure in a responsive manner?

```
<table border=1>
    <TR><TD COLSPAN=6 STYLE="border-bottom: medium solid gray;">&nbsp;</TD></TR>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%; background-color: cyan;">
            <table border=2 style="margin: 1vw 2vw 1vw 2vw;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: thin solid #ff9900;">
                        <figure class="cap-left">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" />

                            <!-- the style sizes here are only to demonstrate
                                 that the class "cap-left" does something -->
                            <figcaption style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                                <div class="icon icon-image"></div>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan=2 style="padding-top: 12px; padding-right: 12px;">
            <center><span style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">lorem ipsum</span></center>
            <br/>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, prima brute at cum, ius tota fugit error te, eum an quod invidunt. an facer fierent iudicabit vix, pri at illud diceret probatus. maiorum ponderum omittantur te per, pri alterum propriae postulant at. ut pro nostro petentium salutandi.
            <p/>est dico stet quaeque no, ei eos dolores dignissim. mei dicunt indoctum deterruisset an, recteque moderatius eu nam. per praesent efficiantur ut, ad mel assum laoreet tincidunt. ad qui agam nullam causae, ut mei minim clita, ut movet verterem democritum est.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <TR><TD COLSPAN=6 STYLE="border-top: thin solid gray;">&nbsp;</TD></TR>
</table>
```

**Fiddle** at http://jsfiddle.net/1kwyew12/

*Note:* The fiddle contains normalize.css v3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`text-align: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align#Values) on the parent element to horizontally center the inline contents.

Then you need to wrap the image in an inner inline-block element.

Then use the CSS [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo element in combination with [`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Values) and [`vertical-align: middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) to vertically center the image.

Also for the spacing around the image to work you have to have to add a class to the table cell containing the table. In this example I use `.left` but you can be more specific.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/1kwyew12/11/))

HTML

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <figure class="cap-left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" />

        <!-- the style sizes here are only to demonstrate
                                     that the class "cap-left" does something -->
        <figcaption style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
            <div class="icon icon-image"></div>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left {
    padding: 1vw 2vw 1vw 2vw;
    text-align: center;
}
.left table {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 64px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
.left table td .img-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%:
}
.left table td .img-wrap::before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
}
.left table td .img-wrap::before,
.left table td .img-wrap figure {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.left table td .img-wrap figure {
    width: 100%;
}
.left table td img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using tables because of reasons or its meant to very old browsers, but my solution requires `display: flex;`

Code added:

```
.icon-image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.icon-image > img {
    max-width: 100%!important;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 64px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Result: [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/1kwyew12/2/)

```css
/*! normalize.css v3.0.0 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */
html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}
body{margin:0}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block}
audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}
audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}
[hidden],template{display:none}
a{background:transparent}
a:active,a:hover{outline:0}
abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}
b,strong{font-weight:bold}
dfn{font-style:italic}
h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}
mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}
small{font-size:80%}
sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}
sup{top:-0.5em}
sub{bottom:-0.25em}
img{border:0}
svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}
figure{margin:1em 40px}
hr{-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}
pre{overflow:auto}
code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}
button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{color:inherit;font:inherit;margin:0}
button{overflow:visible}
button,select{text-transform:none}
button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}
button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}
button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}
input{line-height:normal}
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}
input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}
fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}
legend{border:0;padding:0}
textarea{overflow:auto}
optgroup{font-weight:bold}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
td,th{padding:0}

/* local */
table{font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;font-size:14px;border-collapse:separate}

figure img{display:block}
figure{display:block;position:relative;float:left;overflow:hidden;margin:0;padding:0}
figcaption{position:absolute;background:rgba(255,204,51,0.75);color:white;opacity:0;-webkit-transition:all .6s ease;-moz-transition:all .6s ease;-o-transition:all .6s ease}
figure:hover figcaption{opacity:1}

.cap-left figcaption{bottom:0;left:-100%}
.cap-left:hover figcaption{left:0}
.cap-right figcaption{bottom:0;right:-100%}
.cap-right:hover figcaption{right:0}
.cap-top figcaption{left:0;top:-100%}
.cap-top:hover figcaption{top:0}
.cap-bottom figcaption{left:0;bottom:-100%}
.cap-bottom:hover figcaption{bottom:0}

.icon {
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 speak: none;
 text-transform: none;
 line-height: 1;

 /* Better Font Rendering */
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.icon:link, .icon:visited, .icon:focus
{
 color: #000;
}

.icon-image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.icon-image > img {
    max-width: 100%!important;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 64px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
 <TR><TD COLSPAN=6 STYLE="border-bottom: medium solid gray;">&nbsp;</TD></TR>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%; background-color: cyan;">
            <table border=2 style="margin: 1vw 2vw 1vw 2vw;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: thin solid #ff9900;">
         <figure class="cap-left">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" />

                            <!-- the style sizes here are only to demonstrate
                                 that the class "cap-left" does something -->
                            <figcaption style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
        <div class="icon icon-image">
                                    <img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110704115705/fakemon-creators/es/images/a/a0/It's_something.png">
                                </div>
       </figcaption>
         </figure>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan=2 style="padding-top: 12px; padding-right: 12px;">
            <center><span style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">lorem ipsum</span></center>
            <br/>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, prima brute at cum, ius tota fugit error te, eum an quod invidunt. an facer fierent iudicabit vix, pri at illud diceret probatus. maiorum ponderum omittantur te per, pri alterum propriae postulant at. ut pro nostro petentium salutandi.
            <p/>est dico stet quaeque no, ei eos dolores dignissim. mei dicunt indoctum deterruisset an, recteque moderatius eu nam. per praesent efficiantur ut, ad mel assum laoreet tincidunt. ad qui agam nullam causae, ut mei minim clita, ut movet verterem democritum est.
        </td>
    </tr>
 <TR><TD COLSPAN=6 STYLE="border-top: thin solid gray;">&nbsp;</TD></TR>
</table>
```

This will get an image always centered, doesn't matter if its width is > than height or vice versa

Comment: why do you call this responsive? Would this fit in a phone display? The image is always at 400x300 when I clearly say the max should be 200px and the min 64px. In addition the `figcaption` does not follow the image size.

Comment: I thought you wanted to change the little block that appears on hover